# Java Tyrus WebSocket Client @OnMessage method gets called on 'different' object

Tags: java, tyrus

I have created a WebSocket client using [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/).

The problem happens in the `@OnMessage` annotated instance method.

Within the enclosing class I have three things that seem to both have conflicting instance contexts.

1. I have a Logger instance in the parent class. The getter `getLogger()` returns the valid logger instance.
2. A `LinkedList` object for enqueuing messages. This throws a NullPointerException and is the core problem.
3. The enclosing instance object.

---

```
private LinkedList<String> messageQueue = new LinkedList<>();
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.fromClass(WebSocketClient.class);

public Logger getLogger() {
    return logger;
}

public WebSocketClient() {
    super();
    this.getLogger().info(this.toString());
}

public start() {
        try {
            WebSocketContainer webSocketContainer = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            this.connectionSession = webSocketContainer.connectToServer(WebSocketClient.class, URI.create("WebSocket URL here"));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            this.getLogger().error("Exchange Client Start Error", exception);
        }
}

@OnMessage
public void processMessage(String message) {

    // This returns the correct Logger instance
    this.getLogger().info("Received Message: " + message);

    // This Returns a different hashCode()
    this.getLogger().info(this.toString());

    // This throws a NullPointerException
    this.messageQueue.add(message);
}
```

Through my debugging in the constructor when I log `this.getLogger().info(this.toString());` and that returns the proper package, class name with the @hashCode().

But when I log it in the processMessage() method and returns a completely different hashCode().

Based on my research, hashCode on Object based classes should return the exact same hashCode.

Which leads me to believe that the processMessage is being called on either a duplicate (copy) object or something like that.

Any help would be great.

Comment: tyrus may instantiate some client endpoint classes given how you set up your client endpoint, e.g. by annotation or by passing an instantiated object. Could you please update your code snippet with all class declarations, websocket-related annotations, and how you are setting up client-side tyrus runtime?

Comment: it's a different subject altogether, but mind that `@OnMessage` is probably called by a tyrus managed thread, so watch out for thread interference

Comment: a simple test: did you try creating all your fields in the constructor, instead of inline initialization?

Comment: @nandsito i did try that.

Didn't help.

Comment: it's important to see how you are setting up the websocket client, then

Comment: @nandsito i added the call i make in a method `start` with how the connection is initiated.

Comment: since you are passing a `Class` instance, tyrus will create an object by reflection to attend the websocket messages. You'll have different instances around

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WebSocketContainer to connectToServer I used

```
ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

client.connectToServer(this, URI.create("WebSocket URL here"));
```

It seems WebSocketContainer follows the convention of finding a service provider and that might have been the issue as the service provider could've had a different implementation (Talking out of my ass here).

Comment: is the problem solved? accept the answer so everyone will know it

Comment: It says i have to wait 2 days.